# Printable version of questions/answers or entire discussion

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I don't know how kosher this is for online forums and whether there will be green-erds cringing, but how about adding a feature to be able to print a question/answer or even an entire discussion? Of course, over on [Math.SX](https://math.stackexchange.com/), LaTeX formatting is interpreted to present mathematics (via `MathJax`) as graphics in order provide a nice graphic context. But we also upload our own images (LaTeX output of MWEs, and the like) and provide formatted inline LaTeX and code snippets.

[A similar question over on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82240/stackoverflow-qa-print-view) mentions [`StackPrinter`](http://www.stackprinter.com/), which also provides some sample Stack Exchange printable versions as a demo on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=stackoverflow&printer=false&question=84556) and [Stack Overflow Meta](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&question=9134&service=meta.stackoverflow). This is, however, not entirely integrated into Stack Exchange as far as I know. How about integrating it into the TeX.SX user interface?

Options I'm thinking of include adding that to the list of "actions" one can perform on questions/answers - `link edit print close flag`. This would work well for questions **or** answers. But what about if you want to print an entire discussion (question **and** answers). Well, how about somewhere in the `Tagged / Asked / Viewed / Active` part of the right sidebar? [This answer](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite/876#876) also provides a nice view of a location for seeing a printer-friendly version of a post (question/answer):

[image: Printer-friendly version of discussion]

Opinions?

Comment: see also http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-to-print-out-a-full-q-a-entry-or-forward-it-outside-the-stackexchange-site

Comment: I don't think that adding a print icon will ever happen. It essentially clutters the interface with an icon that most users will never use. Also from a business and community-building perspective its better to just use the link to refer to the page.

Comment: The Greasemonkey script from the answers you linked seems to be a nice way for providing that functionality though.

Comment: Thanks for the link - that didn't show up in my search query or subsequent suggestions.

Comment: TeXPrinter, available at Sourceforge, does what you want. It's very easy to use and allows you to print out the entire thread to a LaTeX file or a PDF file.

Comment: @werner [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298) greasemonkey script should do the trick.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) has developed the awesome [TeXPrinter](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/texprinter) for precisely this purpose. It's a Java application with a very clean interface that takes a question ID and saves the question thread as a PDF or a TeX file. There's a [video explaining the usage](http://vimeo.com/31378263).

Comment: +1 to Paulo's work!

Comment: Nice to discover about TeXPrinter.

Comment: The project has moved to https://github.com/cereda/texprinter

Answer (score 6):

The generic printing option [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/) covers the entire Stack Exchange network.

For [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1680/5764):

[image]

the PDF output resembles:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [Greasemonkey script](https://gist.github.com/kpym/0e595241caeaccefdecdb09d4186c376) that injects the following css (for print) :

```css
@media print {
  * {    
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #content * {    
    visibility: visible;
  }
  header, #left-sidebar, #sidebar, form, .bottom-notice, .comments-link, .aside-cta {    
    display: none;
  }
  #mainbar {    
    width: 100%;
  }
  div.post-text {    
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

The style is not perfect, but hide some of the content to make the page more print friendly.