# About the possibility to save the "answer" in pdf format

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printable version of questions/answers or entire discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/printable-version-of-questions-answers-or-entire-discussion)

Actually I save my "favorite's" answer for future lecture in my Mac, using the printing option and pass to save in pdf format in a specific folder. Nice trick, but exists the possibility of implement this feature (like: print/save this answer) in TeX.SE?.

This is only a question for confort and order.

Thanks.

PD. Sorry for my poor english is not (not is?) my mother-language.